# Pointer type object of one class fails to give output when declared in other class which doesnot inherit it

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, free, delete-operator

This is the code. The program terminates with no output. I searched for it a lot here and on other platforms but all I get is a problem while **freeing the pointer**.
I am freeing the memory in the destructor but it's not giving any output when I use the second object of bmw class to access the member functions of both classes.
Please help me with this code piece.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class car
{
    int weight;
    public:
        void setweight(int x)
        {
            weight=x;
        }
        int getweight()
        {
            return weight;
        }
};
class bmw
{
    car *ptr;
    int topspeed;
    public:
        bmw(int wght=0, int tspeed=0 )
        {
            ptr->setweight(wght);
            topspeed=tspeed;
        }
        int getweight1()
        {
            return ptr->getweight();
        }
        int gettopspeed()
        {
            return topspeed;
        }
        ~bmw()
        {
            delete ptr;
        }
};

int main()
{
    bmw b1(9,8);
    bmw b(5000,350);
    

    cout<<"Weigth is : "<<b1.getweight1()<<endl;
    cout<<"Topspeed is : "<<b1.gettopspeed()<<endl;

    cout<<"Weigth is : "<<b1.getweight1()<<endl;
    cout<<"Topspeed is : "<<b1.gettopspeed()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using `delete` without using `new`?

Comment: Your constructor forgot to `bmw(int wght=0, int tspeed=0 ) : ptr{new char} {...}`  Without `new`ing up a `car`, the uninitialized `ptr` is a loaded footgun with an itchy trigger finger (or... toe?).

Comment: Your class hierarchy is a little flawed... Does `bmw` *contain* a `car`, or should `bmw` *be* a `car`?

Comment: And even if your design would have made sense (where a `bmw` contains a `car`, in the boot perhaps?) then why would you have it be a pointer to begin with? There's no need for pointers here.

Comment: @Eljay. new char? :-)

Comment: You may want something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/1PE6ExoGG

Comment: @Klaus • `char`... `car`... so close.